# C print address of pointer to array problem

Tags: c, pointers, memory, memory-address

When I run the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int array[100];
    int (*array_ptr)[100];
    void *buff = malloc(500);
    int *ptr;
    printf("array: %p \narray+1: %p\n", array, array+1);
    printf("array_ptr: %p \narray_ptr+1: %p\n", array_ptr, array_ptr+1);
    printf("buff: %p\n", buff);
    printf("ptr: %p\n", ptr);
}
```

the result is like this:

```
array: 0x7fffe6dc6bd0
array+1: 0x7fffe6dc6bd4
array_ptr: (nil)
array_ptr+1: 0x190
buff: 0x1f80260
ptr: 0x7fffe6dd417c
```

I run it multiple times, `array`, `array+1`, `buff` and `ptr` all change values randomly, but `array_ptr` and `array_prt+1` never change, although the pointer arithmetic result `0x190` is as expected.

Does it indicate that the array pointed by `array_ptr` is stored in heap? But the dynamically allocated memory chunk pointed by `buff` is also supposed to be in heap and its value changes, why is that? Thanks!

Comment: Your pointer `array_ptr` is *uninitialized*, it doesn't point anywhere, its value will be *indeterminate*. Same with `ptr`.

Comment: And in C you [shouldn't really cast the result of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: Thanks @Someprogrammerdude but why is `array_ptr+1`'s value still available?

Comment: Lastly, the only things stores in the heap is the 500 bytes you allocate with `malloc`. But note that the storage for the variable `buff` itself isn't on the heap, it only points to the heap.

Comment: It so happens that on your system the value of  `array_ptr` is `NULL`. On a PC-like system this is equal to `0`. For a 32-bit (4-byte) `int` then `100 * 4` is `400`, or `0x190`. `0 + sizeof *array_ptr` therefore is `0x190`.

Comment: Also remember that for any pointer or array `p` and index `i`, the expression `*(p + i)` is exactly equal to `p[i]`. From which follows that `p + i` is equal to `&p[i]`. That means e.g. `array_ptr + 1` is equal to `&array_ptr[1]`. And since `array_ptr` is uninitialized that really leads to *undefined behavior* (dereferencing invalid pointers is UB). You're "lucky" that the compiler doesn't actually do the dereference but only the addition.

Comment: This can´t get compiled. You need to `#include <stdlib.h>`in order to use `malloc`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does it indicate that the array pointed by `array_ptr` is stored in heap?

No. `array_ptr` points to nothing, neither on the stack nor on the heap.

---

```
int (*array_ptr)[100];
```

`array_ptr` is *one* pointer to an array of 100 `int` objects, but with this statement you do not create an array with 100 `int` objects by which `array_ptr` is pointing to the first element of this array. It only creates the pointer itself.

With:

```
printf("array_ptr: %p \narray_ptr+1: %p\n", array_ptr, array_ptr+1);
```

You are trying to print the addresses of objects the pointer `array_ptr` and its offset by 1 point to, but this isn´t possible since `array_ptr` is not initialized to point to such objects. Thus, You´ll get any kind of [Undefined Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior)/ unpredictable results.

You need to initialize `array_ptr` with, f.e. the address of the first `int` object of  `array`:

```
int (*array_ptr)[100] = array;
```

The same goes for the pointer `ptr` with:

```
printf("ptr: %p\n", ptr);
```

`ptr` needs to have an address of an object it points to in order to show the address of that object.

> But the dynamically allocated memory chunk pointed by `buff` is also supposed to be in heap and its value changes, why is that?

This is a completely different thing. With `malloc` you **do** allocate memory on the heap (if it was successful of course) and you **do** get a pointer to that memory back, which isn´t the case with `int (*array_ptr)[100];`.

Comment: The undefined behavior in this case seems to be that the uninitialized variable `array_ptr` has the value 0 (whether that happens to be the incidental value on the stack where the variable resides or whether it's a debug mode initialization we don't know); and consequently, incrementing it points "to the next array", which would be 400 resp. 0x190 bytes behind it (the memory occupied by an array of 100 ints). 0 + 400 = 400, which is the address printed.

Answer (score 1):

`array_ptr` is uninitialized pointer, and gets an undefined value(in your case 0).

`array_ptr+1` is sizeof(int)*100 = 400 = 0x190 more than array_ptr

`ptr` is also an uninit pointer, which in your case points to garbage.

You need to initialize pointers after they're defined to get any valid results

To your question, `array` is on the stack, `buff` is on the heap, and `ptr`/`array_ptr` are uninitialized will give you garbage or segmentation fault if you try to access their data